# Laravel 5.2, passing same parameters to multiple routes/views

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a application using Laravel 5.2 and it would have both - a frontend commerce store and backend admin panel.

I want to share a set of variables (cart, company name, logo etc) to front end views. These routes are spread across a few controllers. How can I share the same variables in one go?

e.g.

My routes.php is:

```
Route::get('/','PagesController@showHome');
Route::get('/checkout','CartController@showCheckout');
Route::get('/login', 'PagesController@showLoginForm');
```

And to each of these routes/views (and not the ones in Admin panel), I want to share a variable:

```
 $webConfig = [
'logo'=>'/logo@2x.png',
'company'=>'Acme Inc',
...
    ]
```

Comment: Have you looked at [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers)?

Comment: @jszobody Isn't it used for doing something after a view is rendered? Can you perhaps show with an example how I can use it to pass variables?

Comment: When you have data that multiple views will need, view composers are a great way to put that in one spot and get the duplication out of your controllers.

Comment: Thanks, seems like that is the code that I need.

Answer (score 1):

A view composer can only share a variable between views.

But if you were to opt for the following inside a service provider:

```
config(['web' => ['logo'=>'/logo@2x.png', 'company'=>'Acme Inc']]);
```

Now you'll have `config('web.logo)` and `config('web.company)` available anywhere within your app.

Comment: Thank you!. I actually implemented it earlier, and totally forgot that I can do this.

Comment: What if the values are coming from database. How would you recommend handling this? Still from config?

Comment: Sure, you can do something like `config(['web' => [Config:query()->first()->toArray()]])`